# Many bounding boxes when running faster rcnn demo.py

Tags: python, windows, caffe, pycaffe

I use pyfaster-rcnn to test demo.py,but the results have too many bouning boxes,I have tried to change CONF_THRESH and NMS_THRESH,but it didn't work very well,any suggestions? Thank you!